# Hard Drive space not available when switching from Linux install back to Windows

Tags: memory, crash, hard-drive, less

About 6 months ago, I installed Ubuntu on my desktop onto a 2TB harddrive. After a while, I decided I would rather switch back to Windows. So I took my Win7 installation disk, popped it in and started the installation process onto the 2TB harddrive which currently contained Ubuntu's system. As soon as it completed, I got multiple errors (which unfortunately I did not write down, and cannot remember since it was months ago...yes I know, stupid..). But basically, I could not use the device as my primary. I switched to a different, 1TB harddrive. Now I have time to try to fix the 2TB, but initially when I plug in the 2TB to my BlacX docking station, it is only showing 99.0 mb, which is substantially a  lesser amount. I have tried reformatting several times, defragging, and looking around the web. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or have some hint as to what happened? I did not clear Ubuntu's files from the hard-drive before trying to install win7. Would this be the cause to the errors, and harddrive crash? Thanks for reading, and for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't recognize the Unix partitions created by Ubuntu and is only showing the available space (in probably either previously non-partitioned space or a small FAT boot partition). When you format that small space/partition, its not changing the size - just converting it to a NTFS partition. 
Since you don't want the Ubuntu files, you can repartition the entire disk. In the Windows 7 install, pick "Custom (Advanced)", then pick the drive and click the small link "Drive Options (Advanced)". This should show all the Unix partitions that you can now delete (all of them).
Then create a single new windows partition for the entire disk and you should be good to go.

Comment: This sure seems like the right direction to go and if so is a really good teachable moment, I would take a few minutes to read the Wikipedia entry on Disk Partitioning and get a feel for what is going on. Good information for anyone who has the desire to try switching operating systems or running dual boot computers.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning

Comment: And that is exactly what was going on. It seems to be back to normal. I definitely appreciate the help! Thanks!